# FONTS not showing in PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts

I am new to InDesign. I purchased some fonts for the documents I am working in, how do I know if these are embedded or not? I am already working and when I try to convert my document into PDF, it keeps not showing the fonts. What should I do?
Thank you

Comment: InDesign should embed fonts by default. 1. Which font is it and which type? 2. What software are you using to open the pdf?
3. Did you get a warning from InDesign at the moment of saving?
4. In Adobe Reader, go to the Font tab in Properties and post screenshot

Answer (score 2):

In Acrobat, with the PDF open....

Choose `File > Properties`

Click the `Fonts` tab at the top of the window.

All the fonts embedded in the PDF should be listed.

If there's nothing listed under the `Fonts` tab, then there are no embedded fonts. This could be due to creating outlines before generating the PDF or specific Job Option settings when generating the PDF.